# Django serialize model instance and queryset together

Tags: jquery, python, django

So;

I'm trying to serialize django queryset and django model instance together so that i can use their values in my template.html as follow:

```
# model.py
class PlotManagement(models.Model):
    farm = models.ForeignKey(Farm,verbose_name='FieldID')
    plotID = models.ForeignKey(Plot,verbose_name='PlotID')
    crop = models.ManyToManyField(Crop,verbose_name='Crop Name')
    cropping_system = models.CharField('Cropping System',max_length=20)

# function.py(where i serialize)
def plotmanagement_info(request,farm,plot):
    plotmanagement_instance = PlotManagement.objects.get(plotID__pk=plot,farm=farm)
    plot_cropping_system = plotmanagement_instance.cropping_system
    crops = plotmanagement_instance.crop.all()
    plotmanagement_info = [plot_cropping_system,crops]
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(plotmanagement_info),content_type="application/json")
```

The error that I'm getting is:

```
[<Crop: Bell pepper>, <Crop: Head cabbage>] is not JSON serializable
```

Is there way to serialize manytomany queryset with string model instance

```
>>>type(plot_cropping_system)
>>><class 'str'>
>>> type(crops)
<class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>
```

Comment: You can use those values without serializing them directly--just add them to the context when rendering. If you want JSON output (e.g., to feed data to front-end Javascript code) I'd recommend using django-braces' [JSONResponseMixin](https://django-braces.readthedocs.io/en/latest/other.html#jsonresponsemixin) along with Django's [Class-based Views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/). [Here's an example](https://repl.it/FWpf/0) (you'll need to install Django braces and may need to change your url settings).

Answer (score 0):

If this is going to one time things then there are ways you can pull this off without any dependency otherwise i would suggest you to look into django-rest-framework

In your model definition add a method to_json and modify your view something like this.

```
class Crop(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def to_json(self):
        return {"title":self.title,"field_1":field_2, "field_2":field_2}

# function.py(where i serialize)
def plotmanagement_info(request,farm,plot):
    plotmanagement_instance = PlotManagement.objects.get(plotID__pk=plot,farm=farm)
    plot_cropping_system = plotmanagement_instance.cropping_system
    crops = plotmanagement_instance.crop.all()
    plotmanagement_info = [plot_cropping_system,[crop.to_json() for crop in crops]]
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(plotmanagement_info),content_type="application/json")
```

This is just a quick way to do this.